# Codeigniter - Random Logout

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am being faced with a very weird bug in CodeIgniter 2.1.4 with sessions. I'm storing encrypted sessions into a database. The following configurations for sessions in the config.php are as follows:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'club_session';
$config['sess_expiration']          = time()+(60*60*24); //expire in one day
$config['sess_expire_on_close']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']     = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']       = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']          = 'session';
$config['sess_match_ip']            = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']     = 300;
```

I have set an encryption key within the config.php file as well.

When a member logs in successfully the follow session logic is carried out:

```
$session_data = array(
    'member_login_state' => TRUE,
    'memberID' => $memberID
);
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data); //set member
```

When a member logs out:

```
$session_data = array(
    'member_login_state' => '',
    'memberID' => ''
);
$this->session->unset_userdata($session_data); //unset member
```

I have extended the CI_Controller with the following method:

```
public function member_is_logged_in() 
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('member_login_state') == FALSE) 
    {
        redirect('member'); //redirect to member login
    } 
}
```

Once a member is logged in each controller that serves authorized areas for a member is extended like below:

```
class Hub extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->member_is_logged_in(); // check member is logged in
    }

    //methods below.....
}
```

Now if i access any methods in these extended controllers when not logged in I will be redirected to the login page. When logged in I can be just navigating between a couple of different methods that output different views and I am automatically logged out and redirected back to the login page. This can happen anytime e.g. 1 minute, 2 minutes 10 minutes.

I am really stumped, any help would be appreciated

Thanks...

Comment: This doesn't really help my problem, I don't want to rewrite my entire session control and add another library.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced similar issues when matching on useragent. Try matching on IP instead.

```
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```